# Does the details of login will be stored in database by php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

As an example,in gmail the total data regarding login page i.e email and password are stored in DB and when we enter our email and password,it will be compared with the data in database and ours will get logged.This complete process of extraction of data from sql will be done by php.I am i right?

Comment: Sorry but not quite clear what are you asking, in my understanding, you would like to ask if the user's login process will be logged by database right?? it completely depends on your design, you can do whatever you like to your system, there's no standard.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it other ways but yes you can do it with php. There are lots of tutorials available online to do this.

Comment: k thank you Niall,so  there may be crores of people who had a gmail account,then theirs login details will be stored in DB, such that the columns in DM may be in crores.Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question. But I'll give this example. If you register your account you would save a username and a password. When you log in that username would be matched to a username stored on the database and would check that the password you have submitted matches the password that is stored for that account.

Comment: Also thats alot or records to have in a database. I would imagine when you get to that size it would start causing problems. Especially if you tried something like display all the usernames. But in essence yes their information would be stored in rows in the database.

Comment: If this helped you can you please up vote answer.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you set it all up!

If you are designing a login page you would generally use some form of "hashing" algorithm to hash you passwords and other details. For passwords sha1() and md5() hashing are widely used.

**Example:**

Entered password: `myPassword123`

Database stored password (md5): `487753b954871b5b05f854060de151d8`

Comment: md5 is not considered secure.

Comment: @Niall that is true, therefore you can always add some "salf" to back and from of the string and then do some other encryption ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct a web application like gmail would have a username and database stored in some database server that the web application would have access to.

It is best practice to always store a hash of the password and never to store it in clear text.  You can think of hashing as a one way operation.  It can obfuscate the password but cannot be easily reversed.  This ensures that if your database was compromised the attacker would not have the usernames and passwords easily available which keeps the accounts safer.

As far as implementing this in php goes, php is very capable of creating a web application as are many programming languages.  Any programming language that would be able to be spawned by a web server on an incoming HTTP request (php-fpm for php) would provide access to do what you are looking for.  Other popular alternatives would be ruby, python, etc.

Comment: k thank you so much ddelnano,so there may be crores of people who had a gmail account,then theirs login details will be stored in DB, such that the columns in DM may be in crores.Right?Will DB has such a capability?

Comment: I am sorry I am having trouble understanding what you are asking, what do you mean by crores?

Comment: Its ok,(crores=1 billlion)there may n(billions) number of people who will have a gmail account.If the login details of these n number of people are  stored in db,then there will be billions of rows in DB.Will that wont effect the performance of db?Does really a DB  capable of such a great capacity?

Comment: Ok I understand now, yes you are correct a billion records would definitely cause performance issues.  It would depend on how the data is stored, are the columns of the DB indexed correctly, is this a relational database or a nosql database.  Unfortunately I do not have experience with databases at that scale.  However I have worked with dbs with millions of records and even at that level it is very important to have proper indexes on the columns used to search.

Comment: ok thats great.thank you ddelnano